# PointCloud has no member named ‘serializationLength’

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to migrate some code from ros diamondback to ros fuerte and I am getting this compiler error:

```
error: ‘const PointCloud’ has no member named ‘serializationLength’
```

The PointCloud type it mentions is specifically a sensor_msgs::PointCloud. I am including <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h> as some posts have suggested. What is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53304/pointcloud-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98serializationlength%E2%80%99/) by [astrokenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/4041/astrokenny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-24**:
Are you trying to reuse the same workspace in Fuerte you had previously built using Diamondback?

**Comment by [astrokenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/4041/astrokenny/) on 2013-01-24**:
I'm not using ros workspaces.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-26**:
If you're not using ROS this is the wrong forum.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-02-01**:
I think he meant he is not using workspaces as in rosws. So I am reopening, as I am facing the same issue, and I am proposing a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is what was working under diamondback:

```
void serializePointCloudROS(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud& cloud, ostream& out) {
    out << "Cloud" << endl;
    out << "serialization_length" << endl;
    out << cloud.serializationLength() << endl;
    uint8_t data[cloud.serializationLength()];
    cloud.serialize(data, 0);
    assert(sizeof(char*) == sizeof(uint8_t*));
    out.write((char*)data, cloud.serializationLength());
}
```

And here is what I am replacing it with in fuerte.

```
void serializePointCloudROS(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud& cloud, ostream& out) {
    assert(sizeof(char*) == sizeof(uint8_t*));
    uint32_t serial_size = ros::serialization::serializationLength(cloud);
    boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer(new uint8_t[serial_size]);
    ros::serialization::OStream stream(buffer.get(), serial_size);
    stream << cloud;

    out << "Cloud" << endl;
    out << "serialization_length" << endl;
    out << serial_size << endl;
    out.write((char*)stream.getData(), serial_size);
}
```

And for the deserialization, this is what I had in diamondback:

```
bool deserializePointCloudROS(std::istream& istrm, sensor_msgs::PointCloud* cloud) {
    string line;

    getline(istrm, line);
    if(line.compare("Cloud") != 0)
        return false;

    getline(istrm, line);
    if(line.compare("serialization_length") != 0)
        return false;

    uint32_t serialization_length = 0;
    istrm >> serialization_length;
    getline(istrm, line);
  
    uint8_t data[serialization_length];
    istrm.read((char*)data, serialization_length);
    cloud->deserialize(data);
    getline(istrm, line);
  
    return true;
}
```

And here is what I am replacing it with in fuerte.

```
bool deserializePointCloudROS(std::istream& istrm, sensor_msgs::PointCloud* cloud) {
    string line;

    getline(istrm, line);
    if(line.compare("Cloud") != 0)
        return false;

    getline(istrm, line);
    if(line.compare("serialization_length") != 0)
        return false;

    uint32_t serialization_length = 0;
    istrm >> serialization_length;
    getline(istrm, line);
  
    boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer(new uint8_t[serialization_length]);
    istrm.read((char*)buffer.get(), serialization_length);
    ros::serialization::IStream stream(buffer.get(), serialization_length);
    stream >> *cloud;
    getline(istrm, line);

    return true;
}
```

It compiles, but I haven't tested it yet.

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0